Unable to send Curly Parentheses when using Microsoft Remote Desktop on mac
I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop app on mac and with the mac keyboard viewer I can see I am sending the correct key combo for a {. However, the Microsoft Remote Desktop App does not accept it. Any tips? Keyboard layout NB-NO.
The key combo I am sending is Option->Shift->8 which is { on NB-NO mac.

The solution is to go into the top menu bar while connected in a RDP session, click connections and set keyboard mode to unicode

Check Keyboard Settings in Remote Desktop by going to "Preferences" > "Keyboard."
Ensure that the keyboard mapping is set to the correct language. If it's set to something else, change it to match your Mac's keyboard layout.
otherwise you can use On-Screen Keyboard in Windows:
You can use the on-screen keyboard in the remote Windows session to input the { character.
To enable it, press Win + R, type osk, and press Enter. This will bring up the on-screen keyboard where you can directly click on {.
